# What is the differences between bind model and contain cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What is the differences between bind model and contain cakephp? any one have idea please share with me.. I am new to cakephp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: this answer relates to version 1.3 of CakePHP which is no longer supported.**

One of the most powerful features of CakePHP is the ability to link relational mapping provided by the model. In CakePHP, the links between models are handled through associations.
If you set up these associations in your model, then when you retrieve your data Cake will automagically retrieve associated data too.

The containable behavior allows you to filter and limit model find operations (assuming you have set up your model associations)

https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html

bind and unbind are useful for changing model associations on the fly:

https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the links, but version 1.3 is long gone.